# "Empty Working Set" option in RAMMap

Tags: windows-7, memory-management

What does this option basically do? Does it free the unused memory? If so, how does it affect the performance? In what cases will I use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excerpt from my copy of [Windows Sysinternals Administrator's Reference 1st ed](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/hh290819.aspx):

> ■ **Empty Working Sets** Removes memory from all user-mode and system
>   working sets to the Standby or Modified page lists. Note that by the
>   time you refresh RAMMap’s data, processes that run any code will
>   necessarily populate their working sets to do so.
>
> ■ **Empty System Working Set**
>   Removes memory from the system cache working set.

From personal experience, I just used taskmgr to view the memory changes.

> Initial - 6.41 GB
>
> After opening RamMap - 7.19 GB
>
> After doing Empty working set - 5.45 GB
>
> Close RamMap - 4.68 GB

Also, an image of the same below:

[image]

Comment: Then the follow-up question becomes, what are those "Standby or Modified page lists"?

Answer (score 0):

From the [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533) Help manual:

> The Empty Working Set menu item in the Refresh menu releases all
>   physical memory assigned to the process and then refreshes the scan.

I would assume that the feature is similar for RAM map and that the "Empty Working Set" feature releases all physical memory.